# ¿Error en mostrar resultados en porcentajes y evaluación total del mismo php y mysqli orientado a objetos?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un sistema de valoración de 5 estrellas pero en calificación media y entero equivalente del siguiente **ejemplo:**

`0.5` `1` `1.5` `2` `2.5` `3` `3.5` `4` `4.5` `5`

Tengo un problema matemático y algo de lógica al mostrar los resultados por porcentajes:

```
//Este es el id del producto definido para realizar pruebas
$id_product = 1;

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star,
       SUM(rating IN (3.5, 4))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_4_star,
       SUM(rating IN (2.5, 3))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_3_star,
       SUM(rating IN (1.5, 2))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_2_star,
       SUM(rating IN (0.5, 1))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_1_star,
       AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM ratings
WHERE id_product=?");

$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($pct_1_star);

 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $pct_1_star;
}
```

De la siguiente consulta me muestra el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\votos\rating.php on line 19 ***la linea 19 equivale al siguiente prodigo `$stmt->bind_result($pct_1_star);`***

**Ahora mi pregunta**

¿Cómo puedo calcular los votos correctamente por porcentajes?

¿Cómo puedo obtener la evaluación final del producto?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

col.small {
    width: 30%;
}
col.big {
    width: 10%;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 4px;
}

.star-icon {
 color: #ddd;
 font-size: 2em;
 position: relative;
 display: inline;
 direction: rtl;
 unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}

.star-icon:before{
 content: '\2605';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}

.star-icon.full:before {
 color: #fde16d;
 content: '\2605';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <col class="small" />
    <col class="big" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><ul class="star-rating">
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
</ul></td>
            <td class="percent">40%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><ul class="star-rating">
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
</ul></td>
            <td class="percent">20%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><ul class="star-rating">
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
</ul></td>
            <td class="percent">10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><ul class="star-rating">
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
</ul></td>
            <td class="percent">10%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><ul class="star-rating">
  <li class="star-icon full">&#9734;</li>
</ul></td>
            <td class="percent">20%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Advertencia:** `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()`: el número de variables de enlace no coincide con el número de campos en la instrucción preparada en  `C:\xampp\htdocs\votos\rating.php` on line 19 la línea 19 equivale al siguiente línea `$stmt->bind_result($pct_1_star);`

Como dice el mensaje, tienes un pequeño error, no estas vinculando correctamente en tu `bind_result` los datos que quieres obtener desde tu sentencia preparada. Si te fijas bien estas calculando 6 datos, ya que tienes 5 `sum()` y un `AVG` al final.

*Ejemplo modificado:*

```
$stmt->bind_result($pct_5_star, $pct_4_star, $pct_3_star, $pct_2_star, $pct_1_star, $avg_rating);
```

> **Nota:** es importante que vinculas los datos en tu `bind_result` según la orden a tu sentencia preparada para así obtener el dato correcto en cada calculo que hagas.

**¿Cómo puedo calcular los votos correctamente por porcentajes?**

```
echo "5 estrellas " . number_format($pct_5_star). "% <br />";
```

Recuerda que tu sentencia está calculando estos valores.

**¿Cómo puedo obtener la evaluación final del producto?**

```
echo "<b>Promedio:</b> " . number_format($avg_rating,1). "% <br />";
```

`AVG`, es decir, devuelve el promedio de los valores de datos, es decir, lo estas calculando con la última línea de tu sentencia `AVG(rating) AS avg_rating`.

**¿Cómo puedo obtener los resultados como la siguiente imagen?**

Aquí te dejo también un pequeño ejemplo de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_user_rating.asp)

### Ejemplo completo PHP MySQL:

```
//Este es el id del producto definido para realizar pruebas
$id_product = 1;
//Sentencia preparada.
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star,
       SUM(rating IN (3.5, 4))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_4_star,
       SUM(rating IN (2.5, 3))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_3_star,
       SUM(rating IN (1.5, 2))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_2_star,
       SUM(rating IN (0.5, 1))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_1_star,
       AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM ratings
WHERE id_product=?");

$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_product);
$stmt->execute();

//La modificación a tu código.
$stmt->bind_result($pct_5_star, $pct_4_star, $pct_3_star, $pct_2_star, $pct_1_star, $avg_rating);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    //number_format — Formatear un número con los millares agrupados.
    //Valoración independiente, valoración de votos por cada estrella.
    echo "5 estrellas " . number_format($pct_5_star). "% <br />";
    echo "4 estrellas " . number_format($pct_4_star). "% <br />";
    echo "3 estrellas " . number_format($pct_3_star). "% <br />";
    echo "2 estrellas " . number_format($pct_2_star). "% <br />";
    echo "1 estrellas " . number_format($pct_1_star). "% <br /><br />";

    //Promedio, AVG SQL, es decir, devuelve el promedio de los valores de datos. Este sería la valoración total (por ejemplo: 2.6%).
    echo "<b>Promedio:</b> " . number_format($avg_rating,1). "% <br />";
} 
$stmt->close();
```